# How to abort a Ruby script when raising an Exception?

Tags: ruby, exception, rescue

Is it possible, in Ruby, to raise an Exception that will also automatically abort the program, ignoring any enclosing begin/rescue blocks?

Comment: If you want to abort the program, why not going straight for it and use 'exit'?

Comment: Whilst true, this will still be caught by the `SystemExit` exception: https://gist.github.com/fa5ce273ba27823d0003

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of these `exit` answers will work. `exit` raises `SystemExit` which can be caught. Observe:

```
begin
  exit
rescue SystemExit
end

puts "Still here!"
```

As @dominikh says, you need to use `exit!` instead:

```
begin
  exit!
rescue SystemExit
end

puts "Didn't make it here :("
```

Comment: While not directly related to this question, readers should note that `exit!` also has the side effect of no `at_exit` or `END` blocks being processed which may result in some head scratching under certain situations :-)

Answer (score 1):

Edu already asked: *If you want to abort the program, why not go straight for it and use 'exit'*

One Possibility:
You may define your own Exception and when the exception is called, the exception stops the program with exit:

```
class MyException < StandardError
  #If this Exception is created, leave program.
  def initialize
    exit 99
  end
end


begin
  raise MyException
rescue MyException
  puts "You will never see meeeeeee!"
end
puts "I will never get called neither :("
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this do what you want?

```
begin
  puts Idontexist
rescue StandardError
  exit
  puts "You will never see meeeeeee!"
end
puts "I will never get called neither :("
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to Maran's one, but slightly different:

```
begin
  puts 'Hello'
  # here, instead of raising an Exception, just exit.
  exit
  puts "You will never see meeeeeee!"
rescue # whatever Exception
  # ...
end

puts "I will never get called neither :("
```